# Problem installing gnome-tweak-tool - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, gnome-tweaks

After the last gnome-shell update, the gnome-tweak-tool package was removed.
When I try to install using the appitute command, the system says that I have unmet dependencies. However, I cannot fall back to the required gnome-shell version.

Below I present the command issued:

[image]

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool gnome-shell`

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool gnome-shell
gnome-shell-extensions:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.36.1-1
  Version table:
     3.36.1-1,500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe i386 Packages
gnome-tweak-tool:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.34.0-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.34.0-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe i386 Packages
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Candidate: 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 Packages
        100 / var / lib / dpkg / status
     3.36.4-1ubuntu1 ~ 20.04.2 500
        500 http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main amd64 Packages
     3.36.1-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main amd64 Packages
```

I'm not working on the server, it's ubuntu 20.04.2 desktop.

I tried `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` too, it doesn't work.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
[sudo] user password rskowron:
Reading package lists ... Done
Building a dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This could mean
that an impossible situation was requested or an unstable distribution was used
in which some packages have not yet been created or moved
from the Incoming directory.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  gnome-tweaks: Requires: gnome-shell-extension-prefs but it will not be installed
E: Could not fix problems, corrupt packages stopped.
```

Comment: Can you add `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool gnome-shell` to your question?

Comment: Problem perhaps with your Ubuntu server? Try switching to a different server.

Comment: I think you just need `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` and then run `gnome-tweaks`. At least that's how it is on my (albeit 20.10 setup). I don't really know for sure but I think `gnome-tweak-tool` is old, if I do a package search for it it says `(oldlibs)` and `transitional package`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-tweak-tool&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: Please change your package sources to main server. `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` then try again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible because it was solved by an update to the gnome-shell-extension-prefs package.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. maybe its caused by ubuntu updates.
I tried some more and think that I found, it is because of miss matching version of gnome-shell and gnome-shell-common:

```
~$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-tweaks : Depends: gnome-shell-extension-prefs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

then I tried this

```
~$ sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: gnome-shell (= 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) but 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 is to be installed
                               Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) but 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 is to be installed
                               Recommends: chrome-gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed**
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Update additional details

Hi

I tried fix broken package and it it is saying there is no broken packages.

so if you look at last 4 liens in code it's saying that I have 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 version of gnome-shell but gnome-shell-extension-prefs needs older version 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2.

I searched in gnome-tweak-tool repository issues and there is an issue for it [Can't install tweaks on newest gnome-shell](https://github.com/nzjrs/gnome-tweak-tool/issues/12).

I think we should wait until tweak developers update application. :(

Comment: Hi and welcome. When you fixed the unmet dependencies, was the issue resolved? It is unclear from your answer whether it is a solution or a list of more symptoms of the OP's issue (i.e. a "Me Too" answer). Maybe I am wrong but your answer *seems* to be a bit unfinished.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

A solution using aptitude:

```shell
$ sudo apt install -y aptitude
$ sudo aptitude install gnome-tweaks

...

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gnome-shell-extension-prefs [Not Installed]        
2)     gnome-tweaks [Not Installed]                       

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

...

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Downgrade the following packages:                                                               
1)     gnome-shell [3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (now) -> 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (focal-security)]       
2)     gnome-shell-common [3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (now) -> 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (focal-security)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y

...

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chrome-gnome-shell{a} gir1.2-handy-0.0{a} gnome-shell-extension-prefs{a} gnome-tweaks 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,022 kB of archives. After unpacking 599 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
```

You can then install other packages normally, such as `sudo apt install -y gnome-shell-extensions`.